# How to get Name from ChangedBy attribute in Composite C1

Tags: c1-cms

I need to get full name of an entry. I can retrieve Username from ChangedBy attribute.

How can I get the full name of a username?

Answer (score 1):

```
        var user = Data.Get<IUser>()
         .Where(u => u.Username == entry.ChangedBy)
         .FirstOrDefault();

        var userFullname = user.Name;
```